# Approximation by simple functions on a product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega_i,\mathcal A_i)$ be a measureable space
- $\mathcal M_i\subseteq2^{\Omega_i}$ be a $\pi$-system with $\Omega_i\in\mathcal M_i$ and $\sigma(\mathcal M_i)=\mathcal A_i$
- $\mathcal E(M_1\times\mathcal M_2)$ be the $\mathbb R$-vector space of functions $H:\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\to\mathbb R$ with $$H=\sum_{i=1}^k1_{A_i}x_i$$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, pairwise disjoint $A_1,\ldots,A_k\in\mathcal M_1\times\mathcal M_2$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb R$

Note that $\mathcal M:=\mathcal M_1\times\mathcal M_2$ is a $\pi$-system with $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\in\mathcal M$. Let $$\mathcal H:=\left\{H:\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\to\mathbb R\mid\exists(H_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal E(\mathcal M_1\times\mathcal M_2):H_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}H\right\}\;.$$ Note that $\mathcal H$ is a $\mathbb R$-vector space with $$1_A\in\mathcal H\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal M\;.$$

> I would like to show that $\mathcal H$ contains any $\mathcal A_1\otimes\mathcal A_2$-measurable function $\Omega_1\times\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

As [Veridian Dynamics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/408632/veridian-dynamics) pointed out, this would follow from the [functional monotone class theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_functions), if we are able to show the following: If $H:\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\to\mathbb R$ and $(H_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal H$ with $$0\le H_n\le H_{n+1}\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ and $H_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}H$, then $H\in\mathcal H$.

> How can we show that?

Comment: yes. it follows easily from the monotone class theorem for functions. I can made this into a answer if you like, but you should read wikipedia at least first.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem

Comment: @VeridianDynamics I'm aware of the monotone class theorem, but I wasn't able to figure out why the third condition in the Wikipedia article is satisfied. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Please cross link a question if you also post it on MO. A negative answer has been posted there. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290830/approximation-by-simple-functions-on-a-product-sigma-algebra/291107#291107